# Drag Drop CDK: keep showing dragged element inside starting list

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop

I'm playing with cdk Drag and Drop cause I need it to create a POC for work.
I started with this [code](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nlpedgvrmbg?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts) from the documentation website.
I saw that every time I drag an element outside its list, said element is hidden until I drop it in the same list or in another one.

So tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems that the dragged element is not a copy of the list item, but instead it's the element itself.

In conclusion I want the list to not change its layout while I'm dragging one of its elements.

Long story short:

**CURRENT BEHAVIOUR**
[image]

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR**
[image]

I didn't found anything to do this in the cdk documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stackblitz change in `cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css`

change

```
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

into: (or just remove it)

```
.cdk-drag-placeholder {
  /* opacity: 0; */
}
```

the fact its disappearing is due to css styling of the placeholder.

---

If you want to disable Sorting. Have a look [HERE!](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/15064)

Comment: Yes that's it, but I needed a no-sortable list too. I saw that they added this feature in the last rc.

Comment: This doesn't prevent the item from being removed once it's dragged over the dropzone. It just keeps it fully showing until that point.

Comment: @Ulfius I'm looking for a solution where the original element is always present and doesn't disappear when it's over the dropzone, do you have any idea how to do that? I can't seem to find anyone who has solved it

Comment: @Shirohige Sorry, I haven't seen that they have made an update to allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if you still need a solution for this, but there are 2 events that can help you create a solution for your problem.

cdkDropListExited / cdkDropListEntered
CdkDragEnter / CdkDragExit

The events mentioned are triggered when the dragged element is removed (which is what you wanna avoid) or when it has entered a container.

!NOTE These events are triggered when you move over the target container (but you click is still pressed) => you are still dragging

My solution was adding a custom placeholder div, which I hide/show when these events are triggered.

Hope this is clear enough for you
Peace

Answer (score 0):

Also needed this and couldn't find something that the library supports.

My solution was to hide the whole original cdkDropList and replace it with a look alike.

It won't work for all, for me it works because each cdkDrag is in its own cdkDropList.

Answer (score 0):

The expected behavior is still not implemented till now and there's an open [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20194) on Github regarding this.

Someone provided a workaround for that and it actually worked for me.
Shortly speaking, the solution is adding the dragged item to the source list temporarily, until the item reaches is final destination, where he then removes the temp item from the source list.

Here's a link to the solution which worked for me:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krmecd

The key code to the solution

```html
<mat-list 
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="sItems"
      cdkDropListSortingDisabled
      [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="noReturnPredicate"
      (cdkDropListExited)="onSourceListExited($event)"
      (cdkDropListEntered)="onSourceListEntered($event)">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of sItems" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">{{ item.name }}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

```
  noReturnPredicate() {
    return false;
  }

  onSourceListExited(event: CdkDragExit<any>) {
    this.sItems.splice(event.container.getItemIndex(event.item) + 1, 0, { ... event.item.data, temp: true });
  }

  onSourceListEntered(event: CdkDragEnter<any>) {
    remove(this.sItems, { temp: true });
  }
```